# Screening stocks using Yahoo Finance API (YQL)

Tags: database, yql, yahoo-finance

i am trying to roll my own stock screener using the Yahoo Finance API.

While it is easy to get a heap of data (via XML or JSON) by providing the ticker symbol:

```
SELECT * FROM yahoo.finance.quotes WHERE symbol="RBS.L"
```

(See the results [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol=%22RBS.L%22%0A%09%09&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env) and click 'test').

I am struggling to find a way to find stocks which match a certain set of criteria. For instance, say I want to grab a list of stocks whose Bid price is greater than 20

```
SELECT symbol FROM yahoo.finance.quotes WHERE Bid > 20.00
```

The query fails, with the following message:

```
Cannot find required keys in where clause; got 'Bid', expecting required keys: (symbol)
```

as can be seen [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20symbol%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20Bid%20%3E%20%2220.00%22%0A%09%09&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env).

Is what I am trying to do possible? Is there a way to write the query string to get what I am looking for? Or is there a much simpler service out there that can help me out.

Would appreciate any help you guys can give me.

Comment: Possible, yes. Though not with the `yahoo.finance.quotes` table nor any other existing YQL tables that I know of.  If you find a data source which allows filtering in the manner you need, then it is easy to make that into a YQL table.

Comment: Following on @salathe comment, the Y!Finance YQL tables are unofficial scrapes of CSV files that are used by the Yahoo Finance front-end. They provide a good set of data for a given stock symbol, but can't do range or value searches as you're looking for. You'll need to find a webservice (probably paid or subscription) that does.

Comment: @ZenGyro did you ever find a solution to your issue with yahoo? Is there a table that allows you to screen stocks instead of searching by ticker?